# sequence command and test question

Tags: shell, command, read

Here is a test question that I am stuck with:

Which output will the following command sequence produce?

```
echo '1 2 3 4 5 6' | while read a b c; do

echo result: $c $b $a;
done
```

And the correct answer is: `3 4 5 6 2 1`

I have no clue why. Can someone please explain it to me?

(At first I thought the answer was `3 2 1`.)

Comment: `1` to `a`, `2` to `b` and  the rest `3 4 5 6` to `c`.

Comment: thank you cuonglm.... but the thing I don't understand is why the rest 3 4 5 6 to c?  thanks again - Denny

Comment: @Denny: Where else would they go?

Comment: At least for `bash`, the behavior is documented as follows: *"If there are more words than names, the remaining words and their intervening delimiters are assigned to the last name."*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the read manpage:

> Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
>       if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
>       splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
>       word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
>       the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
>       delimiters.

For this reason I commonly use a "trash" variable to collect anything that may be leftover:

```
echo '1 2 3 4 5 6' | while read a b c TRASH; do 
    echo "result is: $c $b $a"
    echo "trash is: $TRASH"
done
```

---

In use:

```
$ echo '1 2 3 4 5 6' | while read a b c TRASH; do
>     echo "result is: $c $b $a"
>     echo "trash is: $TRASH"
> done
result is: 3 2 1
trash is: 4 5 6
```